# DOM style property in Js

Tags: javascript

Beginner In js.
I am creating a pokedex using pokeapi and want to change the background of pokecards using the colors according to their type stored in an object by using the .style in js

---

Currently I have written this code

```
const typecolor = {
  bug: "#26de81",
  dragon: "#ffeaa7",
  electric: "#fed330",
  fairy: "#FF0069",
  fighting: "#30336b",
  fire: "#f0932b",
  flying: "#81ecec",
  grass: "#00b894",
  ground: "#EFB549",
  ghost: "#a55eea",
  ice: "#74b9ff",
  normal: "#95afc0",
  poison: "#6c5ce7",
  psychic: "#a29bfe",
  rock: "#2d3436",
  water: "#0190FF",
};
const abilities = document.querySelector(".power1 p");//ptag inside pokecard
function generatehtml(result) {
const card = document.createElement("div");
card.classList.add("pokecard");
let newhtml = `
  <div class=pokecard>
   .
   .
   .
   </div>`
themecolor = typecolor[result.types[0].type.name]; //getting poketype from api
card.style.background = `radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0%, ${themecolor} 36%, #ffffff 36%)`;
abilities.style.backgroundColor = `${themecolor}`;//a <p> tag to be colored
}
```

---

Though the themecolor gets console logged out but there is no visible change
working version:https://megahedron69.github.io/Pokedex/
js file:https://github.com/Megahedron69/Pokedex/blob/main/app.js

Comment: What is `abilities`?

Comment: Your code still doesn't reveal `abilities`. It is `undefined` as far as the code you show.

Comment: You never append `card` to anything as far as I can see from the code listed here. You also never call `generatehtml()`...

Comment: why use const abilities = document.querySelector(".power1 p"); since you can add style inside html while creating it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you creating card element but not appending to dom.

secondly, you are trying to get element `const abilities = document.querySelector(".power1 p");` which doesn't exist in DOM.

why not add styles to HTML itself while you are creating card DOM.

optimized code

```
function generatehtml(result, appendToList) {
    const themecolor = typecolor[result.types[0].type.name];
    const name = result.name[0].toUpperCase() + result.name.slice(1);
    const newhtml = `
      <div class=pokecard style="background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0%, ${themecolor} 36%, #ffffff 36%)">
        .
        .
        .
         <div class="power1">
            <p style="background: ${themecolor}">
            ${result.types[0].type.name}
            <img src="Grass.png" />
          </p>
          </div>
       .
       .
       .
      </div>
`;

    if (appendToList)
        searchcont.innerHTML += newhtml;
    else
        searchcont.innerHTML = newhtml;

}
```